# Just what is going on at Gmail and Google with all their errors and mistakes lately?

Tags: contacts, google-talk

I just read through a lengthy forum post on how to remove contacts from Gmail's chat list.  All of the answers there are invalid by now.

My older contacts all have the small down arrow from which I could chose "do not show or never show", but all the most recent contacts do not have the down arrow anymore.
Also the other option, typing a name into the contact search box to reveal options for this contact does not show a "do not show in Chat list", there is only an option to "show in chat list" .. but it is already in the chat list.

Anyway, still need to find a way to remove contacts in Gmail chat latest version, any new ideas, or only nuclear solutions possible now?

Comment: Basically you want to export your contacts list? Because at it stands your question is not written that way at all if so

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: There's probably a question in there, but it's hard to see behind all the ranting.

Answer (score 1):

***"Also the other option, typing a name into the contact search box to reveal options for this contact does not show a "do not show in Chat list", there is only an option to "show in chat list" .. haha, it is already in the chat list*."**

I was just having the same problem/irritation, and found this solution:

When you type the name into the contact search box, if "show in chat list" is checked, simply uncheck it.

If "show in chat list" is NOT checked but the contact is showing up in your list, then check it first, then go back in and uncheck it.  The contact is removed from your list.